# According to Islamic sources, did Aisha gave public speeches?

Tags: hadith, aisha

The Wikipedia entry about [Aisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aisha) says:

> Aisha's importance to revitalizing the Arab tradition and leadership among the Arab women highlights her magnitude within Islam.[63] Aisha became involved in the politics of early Islam and the first three caliphate reigns: Abu Bakr, ‘Umar, and ‘Uthman. During a time in Islam when women were not expected, or wanted, to contribute outside the household, **Aisha delivered public speeches**, became directly involved in war and even battles, and helped both men and women to understand the practices of Muhammad.

According to Islamic sources, did Aisha deliver public speeches?

Comment: If she did so then strictly speeking it won't be called a hadith.

Comment: @Medi1Saif her speeches if exist must be in ahadith المرفوعة و الموقوفة ... !!